# java binding choice box selected item property to a simple double property

Tags: java, binding, properties, combobox, selecteditemchanged

I have double values inside of choice box, but how do I bind a choice box selected item property to a double property?  The code below won't disable the button, as desired.  It seems to me that it's because the **selectedItemProperty** is not an instanceof **DoubleProperty**?  But I can't cast **selectedItemProperty** since it's a readonly property.. What should I do?  Thank you very much in advance!

```
SimpleDoubleProperty valueToCheck = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
valueToCheck.set(314.1)
Button saveButton = new Button();
saveButton.disableProperty().bind(
        choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isEqualTo(
                valueToCheck));
saveButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent event)->{
    valueToCheck.set((Double)choiceBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
});
```